# Where is /etc/initramfs-tools/modules in OpenSUSE?

Tags: opensuse, gpu

I'm following a GPU passthrough guide online which requires me to add "pci-stub" to /etc/initramfs-tools/modules. But it doesn't exist. I'm using OpenSUSE Tumbleweed.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenSUSE the process is a bit different. 
You need to open `/etc/sysconfig/kernel` for editing and than locate the line below starting with:

```
INITRD_MODULES="..."
```

which you need to edit and add the module you want to install.
After this you need to run `mkinitrd` that is equivalent to `update-initramfs` in Debian like distros.

PS: I never done this before so be careful

Comment: That file isn't there for some reason. And I've given up, I'm going to try installing Windows 10 with dual boot

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: /etc/sysconfig/kernel does not exist FYI.

Comment: In my OpenSUSE Tumbleweed even `mkinitrd` does not exist. Some OpenSUSE documentation says do `dracut -f`. Don't know if it's the same thing.